# Login page before main (Aurelia)

Tags: javascript, routes, aurelia

I want when user coming check if he login before -        if not -> redirect to login page -> if his email & password are okay -> redirect back to welcome page.

What problem I have -> service work properly with login class but welcome class totally ignore any changes in service.

## Code

### users.js

```
export class Users {
users = [
    { name: 'Lucian', email: 'lucian1992@zalando.de', password: 'lucian' },
    { name: 'Corki', email: 'corki2010@supplier.de', password: 'corki' },
    { name: 'Vayne', email: 'vaynii@zalando.de', password: 'vayne' }];

securedUser = {};
error = {};
usedOnce = 0;

check(checkUser) {
    this.usedOnce = 1;
    this.securedUser = this.users.filter((user) => user.email === checkUser.email
                                                && user.password ===   checkUser.password)[0];
    if (typeof this.securedUser === 'undefined'){
        this.error = { message: "No such kind of user or wrong password" };
    }
 }

}
```

### login.js

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Users} from 'users-list';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Users, Router)
export class Login {
    constructor(userData, router) {
        this.router = router;
        this.users = userData.users;
        this.check = userData.check;
        this.securedUser = userData.securedUser;  // Changed after check function
        this.userError = userData.error;
    }
    checkUser = {};
    login() {
        this.check(this.checkUser);
        if (typeof this.userError === 'undefined') {
            alert(this.error.message);
        } else {
            this.router.navigate("")
        }
    }
}
```

### welcome.js

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Users} from 'users-list';
import {Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Users)
export class Overview {
  constructor(userData) {
    this.usedOnce  = userData.usedOnce;
    this.securedUser = userData.securedUser;  // This object changed in login.js, but totally ignores in this class
  }
  heading = 'Welcome to the Article Manager Prototype!';

  canActivate() {
    if (this.securedUser) {
      return new Redirect('/login')
    }
  }
}
```

So, tech issue that securedUser changed in login.js, but totally ignored in welcome.js. Is this because of canActivate method? Because I also use activate() - the same problem.

Will appreciate any help with understanding the issue.

Comment: What do you mean with ignored? It is undefined? Do you even get a second time into your  Overview constructor?

Comment: I go to overview, than it check that no securedUser, redirect to login, then in users created securedUser and if check true u re redirected to overview. But overview didnt see changed securedUser and redirect again to login

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for your problem in the official documentation:

```
import {Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  configureRouter(config) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
    config.map([
      { route: ['welcome'],    name: 'welcome',       moduleId: 'welcome',      nav: true, title:'Welcome' },
      { route: 'flickr',       name: 'flickr',        moduleId: 'flickr',       nav: true, auth: true },
      { route: 'child-router', name: 'childRouter',   moduleId: 'child-router', nav: true, title:'Child Router' },
      { route: '', redirect: 'welcome' }
    ]);
  }
}

class AuthorizeStep {
  run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
      var isLoggedIn = /* insert magic here */false;
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return next.cancel(new Redirect('login'));
      }
    }

    return next();
  }
}
```

Notice the addition of `config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);` compared to the regular router config logic.

Source: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/doc/article/cheat-sheet/7
(you need to scroll down a bit to section "Customizing the Navigation Pipeline")

Answer (score 0):

I tried an own example with this and maybe i found your Problem.

You are checking if your `securedUser` is null. If it is NOT null you will reditect to `login`

```
canActivate() {
    if (this.securedUser) { // change to !this.securedUser
        return new Redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

And you are setting your securedUser initial to an empty object:

```
securedUser = {};
```

Because of that your first redirect was working even your if condition was wrong.
Don´t set a initial value, set undefined or change your if condition and check on `sercuredUser` properties.

Comment: 1) change securedUser = {} to securedUser;
2) change check to (!this.securedUser);
Still doesn't work. Show that securedUser still undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your solution might work, but if you have 50 routes that must be authorised you would have to use `canActivate` hook 50 times! That is not an elegant solution for an authorising workflow.

This is a more elegant solution:

Instead of having a "route" to login, create an isolated root component and then update your **main.js** file:

```
//for example, imagine that your root component is located at src/app/app.js
//and your login component at src/login/login.js
//app.isLoggedIn() checks if the credentials/tokens are OK
aurelia.start().then(a => {
  let rootComponent = '' app.isLoggedIn() ? 'app/app' : 'login/login';
  a.setRoot(rootComponent, document.body);
});
```

Now, in your **login/login.js** root component you have to configure the router:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  config.title = 'YourTitle';
  config.map([
    { route: '', name: 'user-password', moduleId: './user-password', title: 'Sign In' }, //route for "username/password" screen
    { route: 'forgot-password', name: 'forgot-pwd', moduleId: './forgot-pwd', title: 'Forgot Password?' } //example of "forgot password" screen
  ]);
  config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
    //if an unknown route has been found,
    //a route from the app component, 'users/add' for example
    //redirect to sign-in component
    return './user-password';
  });

  this.router = router;
}
```

Create appropriated methods to authenticate the user and then redirect it to the `app/app` component:

```
//import and inject { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
this.aurelia.setRoot('app/app');
```

Now, if an unauthorised user access 'users/add', it will be redirected to the login page. If the login succeeds, the 'users/add' page will be shown.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like your decision - idea of it, but I can't understand how to use it in my example. May you provide how it correspond to my task?
Because I see here two root components, somehow new sign-in component and I am totally confused...

Comment: Also I can't understand how in main.js should I have acces to app.loggedIn() method

Comment: Sorry! I made a mess with the names. Take a look at this http://pastebin.com/87WPYgi5 see if it is clearer now.

Comment: Please, mark it as answer if it solves your problem. So you can help people in the future